# Cannot launch FlasklApp with Gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn

Attempting to launch a Python 3.6.9 Flask app under Gunicorn 20.1.0 `gunicorn main:app` in a virtual environment and I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named flask`

The error produced :

```
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4185] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4185] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (4185)
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4185] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4188] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4188
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4188] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/spsimmons/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/spsimmons/Development/Websites/PPSPortal-III/restapi/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4188] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4188)
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4185] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-09-01 08:33:29 -0400] [4185] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Running the app with Python `python3 main.py` runs without issue.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is probably due to the fact that you are using python with virtualenv but you have installed gunicorn outside of the virtual environment.

Try activating your virtual environment and installing gunicorn with pip

```
pip install gunicorn
```

Finally, run the same command to start your application, but using the gunicorn executable installed inside your virtualnev.

Comment: no, I installed it from the git repository using pip

Comment: I suggest you create a virtualenv in which to install all the packages needed for your application (including gunicron). It helps you to significantly reduce such problems

Comment: If possible, also add your directory structure and the command with which you invoke gunicorn